# jsPDF Autotable does not include added rows from a form

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a basic dynamic table in HTML. It add rows using a form. I want to create a pdf of this table using jsPDF Autotable. But it only creates the first row with the tr/th where the headers are. And not the newly added rows with the data.

```
  function createPDF(){     
    const table = document.getElementById('table_fonster');
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
    
       orientation: 'p',
       unit: 'mm',
       format: 'a4',
       putOnlyUsedFonts:true
      })
      pdf.autoTable({     

       head:table,
        columnStyles: {
           0: {halign: 'left', cellWidth: 10,},
           1: {halign: 'right', cellWidth: 20,},
           2: {halign: 'right', cellWidth: 'auto',},
           3: {halign: 'right', cellWidth: 'auto',},
           4: {halign: 'right', cellWidth: 'auto',},
           5: {halign: 'right', cellWidth: 'auto',},
           6: {halign: 'right', cellWidth: 'auto',},
           7: {halign: 'left', cellWidth: 'auto',},
           8: {halign: 'left', cellWidth: 'auto',}, 
           8: {halign: 'left', cellWidth: 'auto',}, 
       }, 
       theme: 'grid',
        styles:{
           fontSize:10,
           font:'helvetica'
        }
       
        })
    
    pdf.save('Windows')
    console.log(table) //Shows the entire table...
    }
```

console.log at the end displays the entire table with the newly added rows.